# C# Get Separate ListBox Items as strings

Tags: c#, excel, listbox

I'm a little bit confused on something. I wrote a code that will count the number of items in a ListBox and then write them into each cell of an excel file. Like this:

```
int test = ItemsList.Items.Count;

for (int i = 1; i < test; i++)
{
    foreach (string itemText in ItemsList.Items)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i, 0] = new Cell(itemText);
    }
}

for (int i = test + 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[i, 0] = new Cell("");
}
```

This writes the code into excel properly however instead of displaying each item in the listbox separately it only displays the very last item in all of the cells. Any thoughts on how I can get each item from the list as a separate string for each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use 2 loops. Do something like:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= test; i++)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i, 0] = new Cell(ItemsList.Items[i-1]);
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the comment as answer if you were benefitted by it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.Join(string separator, IEnumerable values)`

More details: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)